# Codeigniter 3.x, Validation Always Passes Whether Checkbox Checked or Not

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to make selecting one checkbox from a total of four checkboxes required but it's not working. Whether I select a checkbox or not, it always passes validation.

Here is my method in my controller Cargo_inquiry() {}

```
function step_two() {
    $country_to_select          = $this->session->userdata('freight_address_country');                           
    $this->data['users']        = $this->My_Users_Model->get_companies_list($country_to_select);   
    // load up the validation rules for blog Info form
    $this->config->load('validate_cargo');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($this->config >item('validate_cargo_create_step_two')  );

    if ($this->form_validation->run('validate_cargo_create_step_two') === FALSE) {
                    echo "FALSE";
                    // die; 
                     $this->load->view('_layouts/main/template1', $this->data);
           } else {
                   echo "TRUE";
                   // die;
                   redirect('/Cargo_inquiry/step_three');
            }    
}
```

Here is my validation rules located in validate_cargo.php:

```
$config['validate_cargo_create_step_two'] =  array(
        'user_id' => array(
            'field' => 'user_id',
            'label' => '',
            'rules' => 'required',
            'errors' => array(
                'required'      => 'Please select at least one company.',
            ),
        ),
);
```

Here is my view/form:

```
<?php echo form_open('Cargo_inquiry/step_three',array('class'=>'form-horizontal'));?>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="mytable"> 
    <thead> 
        <tr> 
            <th width="3%">Select</th> 
            <th>company</th> 
            <th>location</th> 
            <th>rating</th> 
            <th>web</th> 
            <th>Associations/serv_hhgpe</th> 
        </tr> 
    </thead> 

    <tbody> 
        <?php 
        foreach ($users as $user) {  ?> 
            <tr> 
                <td>
                    <?php // echo form_checkbox('user_id[]', 'user_id[]', set_checkbox("user_id[]"), "Company"); ?>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="user_id" value="<?php  echo $user->id; ?>" /> 
                </td>

                <td> 
                    <?php echo $user->company ?> 
                </td> 

                <td> 
                    <?php echo $user->city ?> 
                </td> 

                <td> 
                    <?php echo $user->state_province ?> 
                </td> 

                <td> 
                    <?php echo $user->name ?> 
                </td> 

                <td style="text-align:center" width="200px"> 
                </td> 

            </tr> 
            <?php  }  ?> 
    </tbody> 
</table> 

            <?php echo form_submit('cargo_create_step_two', 'Next->', 'class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"');?>
            <?php echo form_close();?>
```

Comment: you can use the javascript or jquery it will handle client side nice.

Answer (score 0):

Arrrgg!!! I was submitting to the wrong form :(  So very sorry.